# Arrange ggplot Output Charts on ioslides Slide

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

### Problem:

I am using RMarkdown to produce an ioslides presentation. I don't really know any CSS, but I can hack around a little.

I have three ggplot charts I want on a single slide. Here's what I did in the RMarkdown. (I left the R code out, because the R code works!)

````
## Categorical Exploration
<div class="columns-2">

```{r byFormat, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=3.25,fig.height=2}

```
````

### Outcome

The second chart seems to want to "break" across the columns. I think the best way to solve this is with a grid rather than columns (in other words, *rows* too), but I just don't know how to do this in CSS/Rmd. Another option might be to arrange the charts in the R code itself, but that would be very tricky.

[image: Output Slide]

### Desired Outcome:

[image: Desired Outcome]

Answer (score 0):

Inside a div row, you will put in 2 div columns, later, inside the first div column you will put in a div row and inside of there your first 2 GRAPHS. Now, back to the second column you will put your 3rd graph. Column size is six (E. I. Half a page)

Check bootstrap documents on the grid system. It's based on that.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work, at least not as I understand it. The three charts are generated by a single ggplot; it's using `facet_wrap` to make it 3. So I don't see how I can get each individual chart into its own "cell" that way. Can I use css to give the first two more room on the sllde, maybe?

Comment: this is how it works: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ <br> basically, you want to stay away from facet_wrap, and render each graph individually inside each div. Html's divs will allow you to arrange data in any way possible by the human mind... trust me, dealing with html directly is breaking free from R's constraints

Comment: Thanks Jorge. "Breaking free from R"? I *love* R! :)